# Использование extern:  ошибка error lnk2019

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Я пытаюсь собрать пакет программ (задание по учебе), в файле file1.cpp есть функция

```
int func(){..}
```

в файле main.cpp я подключаю ее

```
extern int func();
```

и вызываю

```
main() { func(); }
```

Но при компиляции main.cpp компилятор выдает ошибку error lnk2019, в чем проблема? Компилирую через cl.exe.

Comment: Кстати, модификатор extern в данном случае излишен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо команда компиляции должна содержать оба .cpp файла.

Т.е. что-то вроде

```
cc -o myprog main.cpp file1.cpp
```

Comment: Вообще-то в вопросе указан cl.exe из MSVC++. Не знаю с какими параметрами его автор вопроса вызывает.

Comment: @gecube, Вы совершенно правы, я тоже не знаю.

Поэтому написал "для примера" вообще `cc`, оказалось - помогло.